# Create a Common Channel where all users can upload video through youtube data api

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have requirement where I need to provide ui to my website users to upload video's on one common channel , Can anyone know, how can I implement it ?

I googled on it but get no result

I know all about You tube Data Api v3 and implemented it, but don't know how to implement it for my website such that all users can add their videos on my own channel.

I get blocked at authentication page because after login each user can add video on their own channel

Comment: This is not possible with the YouTube API ... uploads only work via oAuth2, and uploads can only go into an authorized user's own channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is only possible with [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/). Basically user's will upload to their own channel but videos will be submitted to your playlist.

Comment: thanks , I read docs and it is really helpful. is it possible to add more then 200 entries per playlist ?